# After applying joins in mysql how to get all columns with field is null or empty

Tags: php, mysql, sql

My first table structure and data like this (allowance):

```
-------------------------
|Sno   |   allwnce      |
------------------------|
|1     |    HRA         |
------------------------|
|2     |    CA          |
------------------------|
|3     |    TA          |
------------------------|
|4     |    SA          |
------------------------
```

second table structure and data like this (save_employee_allowance):

```
----------------------------------------------
|Sno   |   EmpID     | allowanceName|  amount |
----------------------------------------------|
|1     |    EM-1001  |     HRA      |  1200   |
----------------------------------------------|
|2     |    EM-1001  |      CA      |  800    |
----------------------------------------------|
```

I want like this :

```
----------------------------------------------
|Sno   |   EmpID     | allowanceName|  amount |
----------------------------------------------|
|1     |    EM-1001  |     HRA      |  1200   |
----------------------------------------------|
|2     |    EM-1001  |      CA      |  800    |
----------------------------------------------|
|3     |    EM-1001  |     TA       |  NULL   |
----------------------------------------------|
|4     |    EM-1001  |      SA      |  NULL   |
----------------------------------------------|
```

I am trying left join like this :

```
Select * 
From save_employee_allowance 
LEFT JOIN allowance 
ON allowance.allwnce = save_employee_allowance.allowanceName 
Where EmpID = 'EM-1001'
```

But it only give result for matching allowance name

Comment: I think what you want is not possible, becaus you have no record für SA in save_employee_allowance so you can not get the row |4     |    EM-1001  |      SA      |  NULL   | because EM-1001 Comes from save_employee_allowance

Comment: use right join instead of left join

Comment: @Jens You're right But I can manage if  i don't get it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want all rows in `allowance`, then make that the first table in the `LEFT JOIN`.  In addition, you then need to move the `WHERE` condition to the `ON` clause:

```
Select a.Sno, coalesce(em.EmpID, 'EM-1001') as EmpId, a.allowanceName, ea.amount
From allowance a LEFT JOIN
     save_employee_allowance ea
     ON a.allwnce = ea.allowanceName and ea.EmpID = 'EM-1001';
```

Comment: There is no need to move the condition to the ON clause. In fact it will give non desirable results

Comment: I think it will not get the expected result, becuase in `allowance` is no value `EM-1001` which is expected in the output

Comment: @Jens . . . Good observation.  That only requires a simple adjustment for this query.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you have to place allowance on left side beacuse  `LEFT JOIN` keyword returns all rows from the left table `(allowance)`, with the matching rows in the right table `(save_employee_allowance).` The result is NULL in the right side when there is no match.

```
select *
From allowance a LEFT JOIN
     save_employee_allowance ea
     ON a.allwnce = ea.allowanceName where ea.EmpID = 'EM-1001';
```